# AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:2382 Failed to set category, error: -50 when category set to .record

Tags: avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder, avaudioengine

```
do {
        // Activate the session.
        audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        guard let audioSession = audioSession else { return }
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio)    //forced
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

        // Start the processing pipeline.
        try audioEngine.start()
        Task { @MainActor in
            isRecording.wrappedValue = true
        }
    } catch {
        handleError(withMessage: error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

For some reason audioSession is only allowed for .playAndRecord. Instead if I set it to .record I will get this error

> AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:2382  Failed to set category, error: -50

I'm only recording, my app doesn't play audio. It's kinda a workaround for now. But is that normal?

Comment: `.spokenAudio` mode implies that you're going to produce audio, so maybe that's why you're getting a -50 = `AVAudioSessionErrorCodeBadParam`. what happens if you use `.default` mode instead?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman seems to work so far. Btw I also get this at the console HALC_ProxyObjectMap.cpp:153    HALC_ProxyObjectMap::_CopyObjectByObjectID: failed to create the local object  HALC_ShellDevice.cpp:2606   HALC_ShellDevice::RebuildControlList: couldn't find the control object do you know what that is

Comment: might be log noise. if your audio session and engine code work you can probably ignore it. I'll turn this into an answer if it fixes your problem.

Comment: its fixed so I can accept the answer if you add one, but it would be great if you can recommend a category and mode combo that is suitable for an app that is just looking to record voice (for voice to text) and nothing else.

Comment: I haven't shipped any iOS code that uses `AVAudioSession` for many years, personally I always just used playAndRecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.spokenAudio` mode implies that you're going to produce audio, so `AVAudioSession.setCategory` returning -50 = `AVAudioSessionErrorCodeBadParam` is not unreasonable.

Set the mode to `.default` instead.